# Задача на Си

Tags: pascal, c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть вот такая задача на Си, написала на паскале, вроде все окей, но не знаю как вывести такое на Си. Заранее спасибо!

Вот сама задача

> Три приятеля были свидетелями нарушения правил дорожного движения. Номер автомобиля - четырехзначное число - никто не  запомнил. Из  их  показаний следует, что номер делиться на 2, на 7 и на 11, в записи номера участвуют только две цифры,  сумма цифр номера  равна  30.  Составьте алгоритм и программу для определения номера автомашины

Comment: забавная задача с точки зрения здравого смысла. Как вообще можно запомнить, что число делится на 2, 7 и 11, что сумма цифр равна 30 и что-то там еще, но при этом не запомнить сам номер???

Comment: Я сама в шоке, вот такое задали на лабораторной, и не могу понять, думаю тут кто нибудь поможет. В чем соль найти ...

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не придумал кроме тупого перебора чисел. Получилась такая вот простыня.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool cond (int x) {
  int number;
  int n1=-1, n2=-1, res=0;
  while (x > 0){
    number=x%10;
    x /= 10;
    if (n1==-1){
      n1=number;
    }
    else {
      if (number!=n1){
    if (n2==-1) n2=number;
    else 
      if (number != n2)
        return false;   
       }      
    }
    res += number;   
   }
  if (res == 30) return true;
  else return false;
}

int main() {
  int x=0, n=7;
  bool is = false;
  while (true) {
    x=n*2*7*11;
    if (x >9999) break;
    if (cond(x)) {
      printf ("Number = %d\n", x);
      is=true;
    }
    n++;
  }

  if (!is){
    printf ("No result\n");
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Здесь использованы некоторые элементы С99. Надеюсь, Ваш компилятор его поддерживает.

Answer (score 1):

```
{printf("%d",  (int)( (11+27)/10 )  +  ( (11+27)%10 )*10  );}
```

> <оффтоп>Вы разбирались в нетривиальных
> задачах с AJAX, а перевести
> простейшую(даже мой кот смог бы)
> задачу на детский язык Си не можете.
> Что-то тут не так.</оффтоп>

Comment: В ответе, как написано должно получиться 8778, у вас же получается двузначное число 83. Перечитайте условие, если вам не сложно!

Comment: >даже мой кот смог бы

эммм..что значит **"даже"**? Неужели можно быть такого плохого мнения о своём коте?

Comment: я переписал ваш код с паскаля на си. Само решения не смотрел.Попрошу кота лучше. 

>    Неужели можно быть такого плохого мнения о своём коте?

Ну вы же понимаете что я имел ввиду