# Задача на do while С#

Tags: c#

Три приятеля были свидетелями нарушения правил дорожного движения. Номер автомобиля - четырехзначное число - никто не запомнил. Из их показаний следует, что номер делиться на 2, на 7 и на 11, в записи номера участвуют только две цифры, сумма цифр номера равна 30.

Нужно написать программу через do while. спасибо

Comment: Пишите. В чём вопрос?

Comment: Не понимаю как писать.

Comment: Пишете цикл do while перебирая все четырёхзначные номера от 0000 до 9999 и проверяете каждый

Comment: по подробней можете расписать?

Comment: Это ваше домашнее задание, а не моё. Если вы не знаете как подробнее - откройте учебник, почитайте про циклы. Если слишком сложно - начните с задач попроще. Отмазки "НО МНЕ НАДА СРОЧНА СДАТЬ ЭТУУУУУ" -- не оправдание прогуливать предыдущие темы. Разбирайтесь, учите.

Comment: зачем тогда на меня обращать внимание и вести со мной диалог, если вы мне говорите писать , когда я попросил полную роспись?

Comment: @Андрей *Не каждому просящему дастся.*

Comment: Как зачем? Вы не написали в тексте вопроса "НАПИШИТЕ ЗА МЕНЯ У МЕНЯ СЕССИЯ ГОРИТ, НИЧЕГО НЕ ПОНИМАЮ АААААА". И бывали варианты - поговоришь в комментариях, уточнишь вопрос, поможешь человеку - все довольны. Да и вам могло обломиться, знаете раз на раз не приходится. Иному электрону не светит через барьер пройти - а он проскакивает, также и с домашкой.

Comment: какая сессия? я всего лишь учусь в 9 классе, нам такое задают и не обьясняют

Comment: все -таки люди 7 лет назад были добрее .https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276019/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как с `do-while` решить не знаю :), но знаю как с `for`.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 7 == 0 && i % 11 == 0 && i % 10 + i / 10 % 10 + i / 100 % 10 + i / 1000 % 10 == 30)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

```
8778
```

> в записи номера участвуют только две цифры

Это условие лишнее, так как и без него остается только один результат. Но если надо его проверить, то `&& i.ToString().Distinct().Count() == 2` можно добавить в условие.

Comment: спасибо , переделал в ду вайл.